# Xamarin entry set line break

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-entry

I have this view with entry control within:

[image]

This is the XAML markup:

```
 <Entry x:Name="txtNotes" HeightRequest="300" Text="{Binding Notes}" InputTransparent="True" Margin="30,0,0,30" />
```

I was expecting there will be a line break at the end of the viewable area of the entry but that's not the case. Is there a property I need to adjust in order to see the text only in the viewable area?

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to use `Editor` rather than Entry.

```
 <Editor x:Name="txtNotes" HeightRequest="300" Text="{Binding Notes}" InputTransparent="True" Margin="30,0,0,30" />
```

You can check the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor).

Answer (score -1):

For the entry/label you can use LineBreakeMode="WordWrap"

```
 <Entry LineBreakeMode="WordWrap" x:Name="txtNotes" HeightRequest="300" Text="{Binding Notes}" InputTransparent="True" Margin="30,0,0,30" />
```

Comment: I try this in Visual Studio and it gives the error "The property 'LineBreakMode' was not found in type 'Entry'"

Comment: LineBreakMode does not exist in Entry control @Luiz